# How can I link two Tumblr accounts to one facebook?

Tags: facebook, blog, tumblr

I have two [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/) accounts and I would like them to be link to my personal Facebook account so when I update content there it will also update my profile. Until now I have been able just to link one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The Official Tumblr App ( http://apps.facebook.com/tumblr-feed/) allows only one user account.

You would need to set up one with the tumblr-feed and the next with a RSS app (http://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=rss&type=apps)